# How to show hide a textbox with label in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an element in zend form

```
$item1 = $this->createElement('text','item1'); 
$item1->setLabel('Enter item 1:') 
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->setAttrib('class','hide_textbox');
```

Here `hide_textbox` is a class in a css file which makes display none .
It's hiding text box but not label, i want hide textbox with label,(i don't want to use `removeDecorator('label')`)
later i want to show this label and textbox using javascript

Comment: Set label empty: `$item1->setLabel('')`

Comment: it's in php i want hide label using css or javascript

Comment: Ok then you should add `javascript` and `css` tags as well in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class to one of the wrapper decorators.

The specifics of this entirely depend on your decorator scheme. This is also not very easily done using the standard decorators as the label and element are inside different wrappers (`<dt>` and `<dd>` respectively).

Here's a quick example but it assumes the rest of your form is decorated to not use definition lists...

```
$item1->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    'Label',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag'   => 'div',
                           'class' => 'hide_textbox',
                           'id'    => 'item1-wrapper'))
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your form a name which will also become its id:-

```
$this->setName('formName');
```

Optionally you can also add a class :-

```
$this->setAttrib('class', 'formClass');
```

Then you can target the decorators through css :-

```
#formName dd, #formName dt{css:rules here;}
```

or

```
.formClass dd, .formClass dt{css:rules here;}
```

I found this by far the easiest way to achieve exactly what you want to do.